# Encryption algorithm for iOS application over HTTPS

Tags: ios, encryption, encoding

I just want to make my server communication more secure so which encryption algorithm I should use to send username / password / scecurity token over HTTPs ? I went through 3DEC, BlowFish , ROT and I am not sure which one should I use. Do we have any stander algorithm apple follows, which can be use for server communication ?

Thank you for the help, -- Amit

Comment: who are you hoping to protect against? And are you worried that the encryption underlying HTTPS will be broken, and/or that someone will initiate a man-in-the-middle attack against your server?

Comment: You do realize that HTTPS communications are already encrypted/secured? Why add on another layer? If HTTPS isn't secure enough for you, adding a homemade layer won't add anything else but some wet kleenex to your 'security' system.

Comment: I do know that HTTPS communications are encrypted and secured. But in some API we developed I just need to pass some token to get very important information. So for that token i need to implement Encryption algorithm. And yes i am worried of man-in-the-middle attack against my server.

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS was designed specifically to:

1. use encryption to defend against packet-sniffing
2. use certificates signed by an authority to defend against MITM

So unless you think HTTPS does it wrong, and we're all entitled to our opinions, then adding encryption on top of it doesn't make sense (to me).

That being said, Diffie-Hellman (optionally plus AES) is one way to encrypt between two peers. The only way to address MITM attacks is with out-of-band communication, which is essentially what signed-by-authority does. There are other ways to accomplish this, such as ship the app with a "secret", or leverage the user's password to encrypt the data from server to client. It depends on your use case and threat model.